# LIMIT does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have a problem when I need range from 10 to 20 (LIMIT 10, 20) it is returns everything from 1 to 20. I don't have any idea why it's works so.
Here is a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
LIMIT 10, 20
```

This table has 5 foreign keys, can it be a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit syntax is `LIMIT offset, rowcount`.  So you're asking for 20 rows, starting with the 10th.  You probably want `LIMIT 10, 10`.

Comment: How, ok, thank you, I use that syntax (limit <limit_from>, <limit to>) and it is works, but it is not for this case.. Thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

The limit command works as follows:
http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Your query should be:
`SELECT *
FROM table
LIMIT 10,10`

the first number indicates which record to start from, and the second indicates the amount of records to limit to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you want with  `limit 10 offset 10`